# Restore Nuget Packages command in VS2015, restoring only XMLs not the DLLs

Tags: .net, dll, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, nuget-package-restore

I got a new laptop with Visual Studio 2015. I have an existing VS Solution that worked well in my previous Laptop.

In my new laptop, I have Nuget restore issue, it is restoring only the XML files not the DLLs for most of the assemblies. Please check the below steps I performed.

In "Nuget Package manager->General" I checked/enabled the below options.

1. Allow Nuget to download missing packages
2. Automatically check List item for missing package

Steps performed:

1. I have downloaded the Solution from the Source control, with empty Package folder
2. I rightclick the solution and selected "Restore Nuget Package"
3. It created the Package folder and all assemblies related sub folders
4. However, when I went into some folders, example the Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.1 folder it contains a subfolder named lib\net45 with only Newtonsoft.Json.xml in it but NO DLLs
5. The Newtonsoft.Json.dll is missing in the subfolders
6. Most of the DLLs are missing in the subfolders and it have only XML files in that subfolders

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please let me know how to resolve it.

First **close all instances of Visual Studio**. This is generally a good idea when doing anything outside of VS that will affect what VS thinks is going on.

Then **try to clear your local package cache**: `nuget.exe locals all -clear`.

You can follow below steps to clear your local package:

First, download the nuget command line tool from [here](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe).

Next, open a command prompt and cd to the directory to which nuget.exe was downloaded.

You can list the local caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -list
```

You can clear all caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Besides, try to **make the Available packages sources only with nuget.org** (Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->Package Source)

Comment: Thanks Leo it works! I have reinstalled the VS2015 also

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829117/nuget-restoring-packages-but-missing-dlls/44829118#44829118) with NuGet seemingly restoring but not downloading the DLLs.

Turned out it wasn't NuGet, but was how I had my version control setup. I'd forgotten to add the NuGet `package` directory to the ignore list for my VCS. In this case, Mercurial uploaded the packages folder but ignored the DLLs by default. When the other machine built the project, NuGet assumed the packages had already been downloaded as the folders were there, though they were missing the DLLs.

Deleting the package folders and letting NuGet pull them down fixed the issue, though next time I'll make sure I put the packages folder in the ignore list when setting up a project.